# Unable create alertDialog in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat

I have an `Activity` which extends `ActionBarActivity`. Whenever I try to create an `AlertDialog` in it, crashes at the the line where dialog is created giving this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

But I'm already using `Appcompat` theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as I'm using toolbar. What could be the reason for this? 
Here is my activity:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_comment);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                AlertDialog alertDialog;
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Network error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Check network connection and try again.");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
}
      });
                  alertDialog.show();


       }
  }
```

Here is my mainfest file:

```
 <application
        android:name=".Networking.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ...



         <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/myactivity"
        >
 </activity>
</application>
```

and, here is the styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Adding the `android:theme` attribute to the activity in MainFest didn't help at all.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/myactivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: You  don't need to use 

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

simply use android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the same exact error. 
However, I think that the problem is the context passed to AlertDialog.Builder constructor. In fact, an activity Context should be passed to it.

Try replacing this line

```
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
```

with this one

```
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

Please let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: Happy to hear so! You could also read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context) to get a better understanding on when to use Activity or Application context

Answer (score 10):

I solved this issue by changing the import :

```
 android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog 

 to 

 android.app.AlertDialog
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

to

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using alertDialog in adapter and in OnBindViewHolder() method as shown in below code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UserListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

//long click for delete the record
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)

                .setMessage("Are you want to delete?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: yes");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: no");
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

}

In this case **new AlertDialog.Builder(context)** is not works properly

so You need to replace it with **new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())**.
This works for me,ty.

Answer (score 1):

It can be resolved by passing. `Activityname.this` in place of `getApplicationContext();`
like in your case
`alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)).create();`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `<application>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything :-(